# Wrong result for FileTableRootPath Function of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, functions, filetable

I just restored a database backup and now the result of the function [FileTableRootPath()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/filetablerootpath-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is incorrect.

Where is the place that I can change to change the result of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a T-SQL example from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/enable-the-prerequisites-for-filetable?view=sql-server-ver15#BasicsDirectory):

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name  
    SET FILESTREAM ( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = FULL, DIRECTORY_NAME = N'directory_name' );
```

Note the database must be locked exclusively for this operation.